# Moving Unique Count Calculation Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am defining a function that is being applied to every row in my Data Frame that counts unique codes in a the column "Code" for every id in the set. The code I have works, but it is incredibly slow and I am using a large data set. I am looking for a different approach that speed up the operation.

```
from datetime import timedelta as td
import pandas as pd

df['Trailing_12M'] = df['Date'] - td(365) #current date - 1 year as new column

def Unique_Count(row):
    """Creating a new df for each id and returning unique count to every row in original df"""
    temp1 = np.array(df['ID'] == row['ID'])
    temp2 = np.array(df['Date'] <= row['Date'])
    temp3 = np.array(df['Date'] >= row['Trailing_12M'])
    temp4 = np.array(temp1 & temp2 & temp3)
    df_Unique_Code_Count = np.array(df[temp4].Code.nunique())
    return df_Unique_Code_Count


df['Unique_Code_Count'] = df.apply(Unique_Count, axis=1)
```

Comment: That was a typo. It should say Unique_Count. I have edited the code and corrected. Thanks!

Comment: You need to determine the number of unique Codes for each ID within 1 year of some specified date?

Comment: Yes. Basically, each row in my data set has an ID. I need to count the number of unique codes that have appeared in last 12 months for that ID, but I need it for every row. It's like a moving calculation that looks back 12 months for every entry based on the ID number.